# Django Left Outer Join

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have a website where users can see a list of movies, and create reviews for them.

The user should be able to see the list of all the movies. Additionally, IF they have reviewed the movie, they should be able to see the score that they gave it. If not, the movie is just displayed without the score.

They do not care at all about the scores provided by other users.

Consider the following `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Record(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "topic")
```

What I essentially want is this

```
select * from bar_topic
left join (select topic_id as tid, value from bar_record where user_id = 1)
on tid = bar_topic.id
```

Consider the following `test.py` for context:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from bar.models import *


from django.db.models import Q

class TestSuite(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        t1 = Topic.objects.create(name="A")
        t2 = Topic.objects.create(name="B")
        t3 = Topic.objects.create(name="C")
        # 2 for Johnny
        johnny = User.objects.create(username="Johnny")
        johnny.record_set.create(topic=t1, value=1)
        johnny.record_set.create(topic=t3, value=3)
        # 3 for Mary
        mary = User.objects.create(username="Mary")
        mary.record_set.create(topic=t1, value=4)
        mary.record_set.create(topic=t2, value=5)
        mary.record_set.create(topic=t3, value=6)

    def test_raw(self):
        print('\nraw\n---')
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            topics = Topic.objects.raw('''
                select * from bar_topic
                left join (select topic_id as tid, value from bar_record where user_id = 1)
                on tid = bar_topic.id
                ''')
            for topic in topics:
                print(topic, topic.value)

    def test_orm(self):
        print('\norm\n---')
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            topics = Topic.objects.filter(Q(record__user_id=1)).values_list('name', 'record__value')
            for topic in topics:
                print(*topic)
```

BOTH tests should print the exact same output, however, only the raw version spits out the correct table of results:

```
raw
---
A 1
B None
C 3
```

the orm instead returns this

```
orm
---
A 1
C 3
```

Any attempt to join back the rest of the topics, those that have no reviews from user "johnny", result in the following:

```
orm
---
A 1
A 4
B 5
C 3
C 6
```

How can I accomplish the simple behavior of the raw query with the Django ORM?

edit: This sort of works but seems very poor:

```
topics = Topic.objects.filter(record__user_id=1).values_list('name', 'record__value')
noned = Topic.objects.exclude(record__user_id=1).values_list('name')
for topic in chain(topics, noned):
    ...
```

edit: This works a little bit better, but still bad:

```
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(record__user_id=1).annotate(value=F('record__value'))
    topics |= Topic.objects.exclude(pk__in=topics)
```

```
orm
---
A 1
B 5
C 3
```

Comment: This question seems very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500066/annotating-a-django-queryset-with-a-left-outer-join

Comment: I am now looking at RawSQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL

Comment: what's wrong with `Record.objects.get(user=mary, topic=A)`?

Comment: it doens't do what I want. it will only get me the records where Mary wrote something, and the topic is A.

I want all the topics, not just A, and not just those for which Mary wrote a review.

Comment: more good resources: https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/236/

Comment: To clarify, based on one of your post comments, is this just for SQLite?

Comment: SQLite would be nice as it is the default for testing, but I just want to know the best possible way to approximate the tidy SQL query I have up near the beginning of the question.

Comment: The uniqueness of Record can be more explicit declared (that the User can have only one Record for the Topic) by `class Meta: unique_together = ("user", "topic")`. It is a fundamental condition for the question and for all four current solutions.

Comment: In the future you'll be able to annotate a subquery onto the queryset: https://github.com/django/django/pull/6478

Comment: @JoshSmeaton, looking forward to that

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271835, https://stackoverflow.com/q/252976

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, there is no a way (atm Django 1.9.7) to have a representation **with Django's ORM** of the raw query you posted, ***exactly** as you want*; however, you can get the same desired result with something like:

```
>>> Topic.objects.annotate(
        f=Case(
            When(
                record__user=johnny, 
                then=F('record__value')
            ), 
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ).order_by(
        'id', 'name', 'f'
    ).distinct(
        'id', 'name'
    ).values_list(
        'name', 'f'
    )
>>> [(u'A', 1), (u'B', None), (u'C', 3)]

>>> Topic.objects.annotate(f=Case(When(record__user=may, then=F('record__value')), output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('id', 'name', 'f').distinct('id', 'name').values_list('name', 'f')
>>> [(u'A', 4), (u'B', 5), (u'C', 6)]
```

Here the SQL generated for the first query:

```
>>> print Topic.objects.annotate(f=Case(When(record__user=johnny, then=F('record__value')), output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('id', 'name', 'f').distinct('id', 'name').values_list('name', 'f').query

>>> SELECT DISTINCT ON ("payments_topic"."id", "payments_topic"."name") "payments_topic"."name", CASE WHEN "payments_record"."user_id" = 1 THEN "payments_record"."value" ELSE NULL END AS "f" FROM "payments_topic" LEFT OUTER JOIN "payments_record" ON ("payments_topic"."id" = "payments_record"."topic_id") ORDER BY "payments_topic"."id" ASC, "payments_topic"."name" ASC, "f" ASC
```

##Some notes

- Doesn't hesitate to use raw queries, specially when the performance is the **most** important thing. Moreover, sometimes it is a must since you can't get the same result using Django's ORM; in other cases you can, but once in a while having clean and understandable code is more important than the performance in *this piece* of code.
- `distinct` with positional arguments is used in this answer, which is available for PostgreSQL only, atm. In the docs you can see more about [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

Comment: This is really good, but I'm going to hold out for a bit in case there are other good answers. Small issues are: distinct doesn't work on SQLite, the very need of the distinct step.

Comment: @RodericDay but the question is tagged as mysql

Comment: my bad! I just picked the auto-recommended tags without enough thought. "distinct" is for postgres, though.

Comment: +1. The only objection is that a unique field should be a added to the distinct clause `distinct('id', 'name')` otherwise a row can be lost if a second object with the same name is possible by accident.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some suggestions. Thanks @hynekcer

Comment: It is interesting that the solution without `.order_by('id', 'name', 'f')` is invalid for Mary. If the order is descending by `f`:  `.order_by('id', 'name', '-f')` then it is invalid for both Johnny and Mary. Can you explain it? Do you think that it will be efficient for big tables as well as the raw query solution?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct, as you can see there, we get some duplicate rows due to this query spans multiple tables, so we will need to prune them accordingly for each unique entry, with `order_by` we set the order so that the pruning performs as we wish. If you compare the two queries you will see the raw query proposed by @RodericDay  should be faster.

Comment: I'm torn between this answer and @Todor's, but this one seems best liked and was way earlier, and neither is obviously definitive, so it gets the bounty.

Comment: Thanks @RodericDay, I think all the answers have a great value, each of them have its own peculiarities and contributions. I'm sure you (and all the user that read this thread) will have a good pool of ideas to face the _left join_ issue from Django. Thanks for the good question!

Answer (score 20):

> What I essentially want is this
>
> ```
> select * from bar_topic
> left join (select topic_id as tid, value from bar_record where user_id = 1)
> on tid = bar_topic.id
> ```

...or, perhaps this equivalent which avoids a subquery...

```
select * from bar_topic
left join bar_record
on bar_record.topic_id = bar_topic.id and bar_record.user_id = 1
```

---

> I want to know how to do this effectively, or, if it is impossible, an explanation of why it is impossible...

Unless you use raw queries, it's impossible with Django's ORM, and here's why.

`QuerySet` objects (`django.db.models.query.QuerySet`) have a `query` attribute (`django.db.models.sql.query.Query`) which is a representation of the actual query which will be performed. These `Query` objects helpfully have a `__str__` method, so you can print it out to see what it is.

Let's start with a simple `QuerySet`...

```
>>> from bar.models import *
>>> qs = Topic.objects.filter(record__user_id=1)
>>> print qs.query
SELECT "bar_topic"."id", "bar_topic"."name" FROM "bar_topic" INNER JOIN "bar_record" ON ("bar_topic"."id" = "bar_record"."topic_id") WHERE "bar_record"."user_id" = 1
```

...which is obviously not going to work, due to the `INNER JOIN`.

Taking a deeper look inside the `Query` object, there's an `alias_map` attribute which determines what table joins will be performed...

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(qs.query.alias_map)
{u'bar_record': JoinInfo(table_name=u'bar_record', rhs_alias=u'bar_record', join_type='INNER JOIN', lhs_alias=u'bar_topic', lhs_join_col=u'id', rhs_join_col='topic_id', nullable=True),
 u'bar_topic': JoinInfo(table_name=u'bar_topic', rhs_alias=u'bar_topic', join_type=None, lhs_alias=None, lhs_join_col=None, rhs_join_col=None, nullable=False),
 u'auth_user': JoinInfo(table_name=u'auth_user', rhs_alias=u'auth_user', join_type='INNER JOIN', lhs_alias=u'bar_record', lhs_join_col='user_id', rhs_join_col=u'id', nullable=False)}
```

Note that Django only supports two possible `join_type`s, `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59bea9efd2768102fc9d3aedda469502c218e9b7/django/db/models/sql/constants.py#L22)).

Now, we *can* use the `Query` object's `promote_joins` methods to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `bar_record` table...

```
>>> qs.query.promote_joins(['bar_record'])
>>> pprint(qs.query.alias_map)
{u'bar_record': JoinInfo(table_name=u'bar_record', rhs_alias=u'bar_record', join_type='LEFT OUTER JOIN', lhs_alias=u'bar_topic', lhs_join_col=u'id', rhs_join_col='topic_id', nullable=True),
 u'bar_topic': JoinInfo(table_name=u'bar_topic', rhs_alias=u'bar_topic', join_type=None, lhs_alias=None, lhs_join_col=None, rhs_join_col=None, nullable=False),
 u'auth_user': JoinInfo(table_name=u'auth_user', rhs_alias=u'auth_user', join_type='LEFT OUTER JOIN', lhs_alias=u'bar_record', lhs_join_col='user_id', rhs_join_col=u'id', nullable=False)}
```

...which will change the query to...

```
>>> print qs.query
SELECT "bar_topic"."id", "bar_topic"."name" FROM "bar_topic" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bar_record" ON ("bar_topic"."id" = "bar_record"."topic_id") WHERE "bar_record"."user_id" = 1
```

...however, this is still no use, since the join will always match a row, even if it doesn't belong to the correct user, and the `WHERE` clause will filter it out.

Using `values_list()` automatically influences the `join_type`...

```
>>> qs = Topic.objects.filter(record__user_id=1).values_list('name', 'record__value')
>>> print qs.query
SELECT "bar_topic"."name", "bar_record"."value" FROM "bar_topic" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bar_record" ON ("bar_topic"."id" = "bar_record"."topic_id") WHERE "bar_record"."user_id" = 1
```

...but ultimately suffers from the same problem.

There is, unfortunately, a fundamental limitation in the joins generated by the ORM, in that they can only be of the form...

```
(LEFT OUTER|INNER) JOIN <lhs_alias> ON (<lhs_alias>.<lhs_join_col> = <rhs_alias>.<rhs_join_col>)
```

...so there's really no way to achieve your desired SQL, other than using a raw query.

Sure, you can hack around with things like `annotate()` and `extra()`, but they'll likely generate queries which are far less performant, and arguably no more readable than raw SQL.

---

> ...and a suggested alternative.

Personally, I'd just use the raw query...

```
select * from bar_topic
left join bar_record
on bar_record.topic_id = bar_topic.id and bar_record.user_id = 1
```

...which is simple enough to be compatible with all of Django's supported backends.

Comment: This is essentially the only documentation I've found on the inner workings of Query (other than comments in the code), so thank you for this answer

Answer (score 11):

This **more universal solution** inspired by [trinchet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108285/448474) works also with other databases:

```
>>> qs = Topic.objects.annotate(
...         f=Max(Case(When(record__user=johnny, then=F('record__value'))))
... )
```

example data

```
>>> print(qs.values_list('name', 'f'))
[(u'A', 1), (u'B', None), (u'C', 3)]
```

verify the query

```
>>> print(qs.query)  # formated and removed excessive double quotes
SELECT bar_topic.id, bar_topic.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bar_record.user_id = 1 THEN bar_record.value ELSE NULL END) AS f
FROM bar_topic LEFT OUTER JOIN bar_record ON (bar_topic.id = bar_record.topic_id)
GROUP BY bar_topic.id, bar_topic.name
```

**Advantages** (compared to the original solutions)

- It works also with SQLite.
- The query set can be easily filtered or sorted, no matter how.
- No type cast `output_field` is necessary.
- The methods `values` or `values_list(*field_names)` are useful for a more simple `GROUP BY`, but they are not necessary.

The left join can be made more readable by writing a function:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Case, When, F

def left_join(result_field, **lookups):
    return Max(Case(When(then=F(result_field), **lookups)))

>>> Topic.objects.annotate(
...         record_value=left_join('record__value', record__user=johnny),
... ).values_list('name', 'record_value')
```

More fields from Record can be added by `anotate` method to results this way with nice mnemonic names.

I agree with other authors that it can be optimized, but [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).

**EDIT**: The same result comes if the aggregation function `Max` is replaced by `Min`. Both Min and Max ignore NULL values and can be used on any type, e.g. for strings. The aggregation is useful if the left join is not guaranteed to be unique. If the field is numeric than it can be useful to use average value `Avg` on the left join.

Answer (score 9):

### Raw Queries.

```
topics = Topic.objects.raw('''
            select * from bar_topic
            left join (select topic_id as tid, value from bar_record where user_id = 1) AS subq
            on tid = bar_topic.id
            ''')
```

You seem to know the answer yourself. There is nothing wrong with using a raw query when you can't get the ORM query to behave exactly the way you want it to.

One main drawback with raw queries is that they are not cached like ORM queries. That means if you iterate through the raw queryset twice, the query will be repeated. Another is that you cannot call .count() on it.

### Null Foreign Keys

You can force the ORM to use LEFT OUTER JOIN BY setting `null=True` in the foreign keys. Do this with the tables as they are.

```
print Record.objects.filter(user_id=8).select_related('topic').query
```

The result is

```
SELECT "bar_record"."id", "bar_record"."user_id", "bar_record"."topic_id", "bar_record"."value", "bar_topic"."id", "bar_topic"."name" FROM "bar_record"
INNER JOIN "bar_topic" ON ( "bar_record"."topic_id" = "bar_topic"."id" ) WHERE "bar_record"."user_id" = 8
```

Now set, null=True and perform the same ORM query as above. The result is

```
SELECT "bar_record"."id", "bar_record"."user_id", "bar_record"."topic_id", "bar_record"."value", "bar_topic"."id", "bar_topic"."name" FROM "bar_record" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "bar_topic" ON ( "bar_record"."topic_id" = "bar_topic"."id" ) WHERE "bar_record"."user_id" = 8
```

Note how the query has suddenly changed to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But we are not out of the woods yet because the order of tables should be reversed! Thus unless you can restructure your models, an ORM LEFT OUTER JOIN may not be entirely possible without chaining or UNION both of which you have tried out already.

Comment: This left join is not a problem and you need a right join in this query now. Every Record has a Topic, but not every Topic has a Record.

Comment: exactly @hynekcer , that's what I too was trying to point out

Comment: (I'm sorry. Twenty years ago my chief that he could read a Spanish book if there is enough formulas. :-) Now I have read only formulas.) Yesterday I did grep through django.db for left join, outer join and related internal structures o tre query. The result is that only two circumstances can cause the OUTER (left/right) JOIN. It is a foreign key with null=True or an OR condition, because a condition `foreignkey_a.name='A' OR foreignkey_b.name='B'` could give invalid results if the related tables are joined by inner join. The solution by @trinchet is based on the OR type logic.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I would do it. Two queries, not one:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    #...

    @property
    def user_value(self):
        try:
            return self.user_records[0].value
        except IndexError:
            #This topic does not have 
            #a review by the request.user
            return None
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('You forgot to prefetch the user_records')
            #or you can just
            return None

#usage
topics = Topic.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch('record_set',
        queryset=Record.objects.filter(user=request.user),
        to_attr='user_records'
    )
)

for topic in topics:
    print topic.user_value
```

The benefit is that you get the whole `Record` object. So consider a situation where you want to not only show the `value`, but the `time-stamp` also.

Just for the record I want to show one more solution using `.extra`. I'm impressed no one has mention it, because it should produce the best possible performance.

```
topics = Topic.objects.all().extra(
    select={
        'user_value': """SELECT value FROM myapp_record 
            WHERE myapp_record.user_id = %s
            AND myapp_record.topic_id = myapp_topic.id 
        """
    },
    select_params=(request.user.id,)
)

for topic in topics
    print topic.user_value
```

Both solutions can be abstracted into a custom `TopicQuerySet` class for re-usability.

```
class TopicQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def prefetch_user_records(self, user):
        return self.prefetch_related(
            models.Prefetch('record_set',
                queryset=Record.objects.filter(user=request.user),
                to_attr='user_records'
            )
        )

    def annotate_user_value(self, user):
        return self.extra(
            select={
                'user_value': """SELECT value FROM myapp_record 
                    WHERE myapp_record.user_id = %s
                    AND myapp_record.topic_id = myapp_topic.id 
                """
            },
            select_params=(user.id,)
        )

class Topic(models.Model):
    #...

    objects = TopicQuerySet.as_manager()


#usage
topics = Topic.objects.all().annotate_user_value(request.user)
#or
topics = Topic.objects.all().prefetch_user_records(request.user)

for topic in topics:
    print topic.user_value
```

Comment: I like your suggestion with `Prefetch`, but it's a pity this requires another query and that `user_records` will be a `QuerySet` where one could expect it to be simply a single `Record` (although there is no `UNIQUE` constraint mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 6):

Django 2.0 introduced [`FilteredRelation` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects), which I believe are what you want. This

```
print('\nnew orm\n---')
with self.assertNumQueries(1):
    topics = Topic.objects.annotate(
        filtered_record=FilteredRelation(
            'record', condition=Q(record__user_id=1)
        )
    ).values_list('name', 'filtered_record__value')

    for topic in topics:
        print(*topic)
```

produces the expected table:

```
new orm
---
A 1
B None
C 3
```

The query Django outputs:

```
SELECT "bar_topic"."name", filtered_record."value" 
FROM "bar_topic" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bar_record" filtered_record 
ON ("bar_topic"."id" = filtered_record."topic_id" 
AND (filtered_record."user_id" = 1))
```

Comment: Dude, you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this out here since it solved our issue and it may help someone else.

- We had two tables, let's call them Client and Contract.
- Client refers to Contract via a foreign key (many to one)
- For some Client-records the Contract-record was deleted
- We wanted to find the Clients which referred to Contract which no longer existed

We started out using `OuterRef` but both Client and Contract are very large tables. `OuterRef` is translated to a `WHERE EXISTS`, which was painfully slow. A lot of the above options also didn't work for us. Here is what we did.

```py
from django.db.models.sql.constants import LOUTER

queryset = Client.objects.filter(contract__date=None)
queryset.query.alias_map['contract'].join_type = LOUTER
```

Running `print(str(queryset.query))` does indeed yield a query with a left outer join and the results also matches expectations.

Closing observations:

- `contract__id=None` wouldn't work because Django is too clever for its own good and just checks `contract_id=None` on the child table, which isn't what you're looking for with orphaned records. We picked a `NOT NULL` field in the parent table (`contract__date` in our example), forcing Django to make the join.
- Inspect the `alias_map` to see how Django has named your aliases.