# Automatically annotate Django models retrieved through a ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Student` model that's related to a `Course` model through a `ManyToMany` field:

```
class Student(Model):
    name = TextField()

class Course(Model):
    name = TextField()
    students = ManyToManyField(Student, through="StudentCourse")

class StudentCourse(Model):
    student = ForeignKey(Student)
    course = ForeignKey(Course)
    section_name = TextField()
```

How can I automatically annotate students retrieved through the `Course.students` many-to-many field with their section in that course?

For example, instead of having to add the explicit `extra` on each query:

```
>>> students = course.students.extra(select={
...     "section_name": "app_student_course.section_name",
... })
>>> print students[0].section_name
u'First Section'
```

I can just:

```
>>> students = course.students.all()
>>> print students[0].section_name
u'First Section'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible to replace the relation manager as follows. From there you can do whatever you want with the queryset:

```
from django.db.models.query import F

class Student(Model):
    name = TextField()

class Course(Model):
    name = TextField()
    students = ManyToManyField(Student, through="StudentCourse")

class StudentCourse(Model):
    # Set related_names so that it is easy to refer to the relation
    # with the through model
    student = ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student_courses')
    course = ForeignKey(Course, related_name='student_courses')
    section_name = TextField()

# Create a new customized manager
class StudentRelatedWithCourseManager(
    Course.students.related_manager_cls
):

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Gets the queryset of related Students ... 
        qs = super(StudentRelatedWithCourseManager, self)\
            .get_queryset()

        # Annotate it before is handled by the ManyRelatedDescriptor
        return qs.annotate(
            section_name=F('student_courses__section_name')
        )

# Replace the stock manager with your custom manager
Course.students.related_manager_cls = \
    StudentRelatedWithCourseManager
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say the problem here is very similar with [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060232/django-left-outer-join/38132258#38132258) here, so my solution is almost identical to the one provided there.

I think `prefetch_related` with custom `Prefetch` is more suitable for such kind of problems instead of `.annotations` or `.extra` clauses. The benefit is that you get the whole related object instead of a single bit of it (so you can use more metadata), and there is zero performance drawback, only bigger memory footprint which can cause problems if its used for a large set of objects.

```
class StudenQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def prefetch_sections_for_course(self, course):
        return self.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('studentcourse_set',
            queryset=StudentCourse.objects.filter(course=course),
            to_attr='course_sections'
        ))

class Student(Model):
    name = TextField()

    objects = StudenQuerySet.as_manager()

    @property
    def course_section_name(self):
        try:
            return self.course_sections[0].section_name
        except IndexError:
            #This student is not related with the prefetched course
            return None
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('You forgot to prefetch course sections')
            #or you can just
            return None

#usage
students = course.students.all().prefetch_sections_for_course(course)
for student in students:
    print student.course_section_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just query the `StudentCourse` model? For example:

```
StudentCourse.objects.filter(course=course)
```

If you're iterating over `StudentCourse` objects and querying the `student` property, use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make sure that you're not doing an additional DB Query for each Student.

```
student_courses = StudentCourse.objects.select_related('student').filter(course=course)
for sc in student_courses:
    print '%s: %s' % (sc.student.name, sc.section_name)
```

Comment: Because that will yield `StudentCourse` objects, not `Student`s.

Comment: And `StudentCourse` objects have a `student` property that holds a `Student` object. Help me to understand your use case better.

Comment: My use case is exactly what I've described in the question: I'd like the students from `course.students` to have their `section_name `automatically included. There are a bunch of reasonable ways to achieve a *similar* result (you've got a good one, I've also listed one in the question)… but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't understand why you'd *want* the `section_name` to be accessible as a property of a `Student` when it's clearly a property related to both a specific student **and** a specific course. A, *`StudentCourse`*, if you will. ;) That said, no, I don't believe there's a way to do specifically what you want, and I don't think there ought to be a mechanism to magically attach arbitrary properties from other models to a model. If you're going to do something like this, it ought to be explicit.

Comment: You might be able to do what you're looking for with a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/). Even then, though, it doesn't add a property to the objects returned by the default manager (which is a good thing!) so it seems like you're just hiding the 'extra' behind a layer of abstraction.

Comment: Yea, managers are definitely the way to go. But I'm not sure how to attach a specific manager to just _that_ relation, as [`use_for_related_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#manager-types) seems to apply to _all_ relations, which (in this case) clearly doesn't make sense.

Comment: "and I don't think there ought to be a mechanism to magically attach arbitrary properties from other models to a model" I guess we'll have to [agree](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) [to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) [disagree](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on that one, then :)

Comment: By 'magically', I mean transparently. You're trying to avoid having to use `extra` and have that logic happen "automatically". Down the road, that will lead to confusion. I think that the fact that `extra` looks ugly to you should be a red flag, and you should consider changing your perspective on how you're querying your data. Case in point: `section_name` **is** a property of a `StudentCourse`. Don't hide that!