# How to left outer join with extra condition in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have these three models:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    artist = models.TextField()

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class TrackHasTag(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey('Track', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And I want to retrieve all Tracks that are not tagged with a specific tag. This gets me what I want: `Track.objects.exclude(trackhastag__tag_id='1').only('id')` but it's very slow when the tables grow. This is what I get when printing `.query` of the queryset:

```
SELECT "track"."id" 
FROM   "track" 
WHERE  NOT ( "track"."id" IN (SELECT U1."track_id" AS Col1 
                              FROM   "trackhastag" U1 
                              WHERE  U1."tag_id" = 1) )
```

I would like Django to send this query instead:

```
SELECT "track"."id" 
FROM   "track" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "trackhastag" 
                    ON "track"."id" = "trackhastag"."track_id" 
                       AND "trackhastag"."tag_id" = 1 
WHERE  "trackhastag"."id" IS NULL;
```

But haven't found a way to do so. Using a Raw Query is not really an option as I have to filter the resulting queryset very often.

The cleanest workaround I have found is to create a view in the database and a model `TrackHasTagFoo` with `managed = False` that I use to query like: `Track.objects.filter(trackhastagfoo__isnull=True)`. I don't think this is an elegant nor sustainable solution as it involves adding Raw SQL to my migrations to mantain said view.

This is just one example of a situation where we need to do this kind of left join with an extra condition, but the truth is that we are facing this problem in more parts of our application.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Track.objects.exclude(trackhastag__name='new_release').only('id')` it is wrong query for the models in the question.

Comment: @BearBrown You are right. It is corrected now. Sorry!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in [Django #29555](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29555#comment:2) you can use `FilteredRelation` for this purpose [since Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects).

```
Track.objects.annotate(
    has_tag=FilteredRelation(
        'trackhastag', condition=Q(trackhastag__tag=1)
    ),
).filter(
    has_tag__isnull=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about queryset extras? They do not break ORM and can be further filtered (vs RawSQL)

```
from django.db.models import Q

Track.objects.filter(
  # work around to force left outer join
  Q(trackhastag__isnull=True) | Q(trackhastag__isnull=False)
).extra(
    # where parameters are “AND”ed to any other search criteria
    # thus we need to account for NULL
    where=[
        '"app_trackhastag"."id" <> %s or "app_trackhastag"."id" is NULL'
    ],
    params=[1],
)
```

produces this somewhat convoluted query:

```
SELECT "app_track"."id", "app_track"."title", "app_track"."artist"
FROM "app_track"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_trackhastag"
ON ("app_track"."id" = "app_trackhastag"."track_id")
WHERE (
    ("app_trackhastag"."id" IS NULL OR "app_trackhastag"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND
    ("app_trackhastag"."id" <> 1 or "app_trackhastag"."id" is NULL)
)
```

## Rationale

### Step 1

One straight forward way to have a left outer join with queryset is the following:

```
Track.objects.filter(trackhastag__isnull=True)
```

which gives:

```
SELECT "app_track"."id", "app_track"."title", "app_track"."artist"
FROM "app_track"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_trackhastag"
ON ("app_track"."id" = "app_trackhastag"."track_id")
WHERE "app_trackhastag"."id" IS NULL
```

### Step 2

Realize that once step 1 is done (we have a left outer join), we can leverage 
[queryset's extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
Track.objects.filter(
    trackhastag__isnull=True
).extra(
    where=['"app_trackhastag"."id" <> %s'],
    params=[1],
)
```

which gives:

```
SELECT "app_track"."id", "app_track"."title", "app_track"."artist"
FROM "app_track"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_trackhastag"
ON ("app_track"."id" = "app_trackhastag"."track_id")
WHERE (
    "app_trackhastag"."id" IS NULL AND
    ("app_trackhastag"."id" <> 1)
)
```

### Step 3

Playing around `extra` limitations (*All where parameters are “AND”ed to any other search criteria*) to come up with final solution above.

Answer (score -1):

Using filters is better than exclude... because wit exclude they will get the entire query first and only than excluding the itens you dont want, while filter get only what you want Like you said *Track.objects.filter(trackhastagfoo__isnull=True)* is better than Exclude one.

**Suggestion:** You trying to manually do one ManyToMany Relations, as Mohammad said, why you dont try use ManyToManyField? is more easy to use

Maybe this answer your question: [Django Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060232/django-left-outer-join)

Comment: This does not really answer my question. I already replied to Mohammed saying that an explicit ManyToMany relation does the exact same query than my example.

Answer (score -2):

Enric, why you did not use many to many relation

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    artist = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And for your question

```
Track.objects.filter(~Q(tags__id=1))
```

Comment: This results in the exact same query that I Django is doing in my example except for the table names.