# Can't make Django raw sql working correctly

Tags: mysql, django

I need to make inner join query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounting_supplier as s 
    LEFT JOIN  ( 
    SELECT position, supplier_id FROM accounting_supplierposition WHERE user_id = %s 
    ) as sp on sp.supplier_id = s.id 
    ORDER BY sp.position", [request.user]
```

Models look like:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class SupplierPosition(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I've tried different approaches but no one gives the result I want. 
There is a way described here: [Django Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060232/django-left-outer-join)
but distinct does not work with MySQL, so I decided to use RAW.
But it seems that ordering doesn't work correctly. If I copy/paste sql from my code to mysql command line it works fine but in Django it does make selection but no order.

Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please describe your original task/need. Sample data and desired result would also be helpful.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, thank you. Guy from habr helped to figure it out already. I used representation of user but not id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small mistake: not [request.user] but [request.user.id]. I used representation of user but not id